# Creating a Class from multiple Models - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 4 Models, each defined as follows

```
--Model/Table--
Competition
Matches
Goals
Teams
```

These 4 models completes a season's worth of soccer league data. The relationship between these tables are already defined. Now, I want to create a class where it picks up data from all 4 models and generate 1, new class. Like so :

```
class CompetitionSeason < ApplicationRecord
    # Use data from all 4 models to construct a soccer season class
end
```

That is my intention, but I'm not sure if this is the best practice for doing so. It feels... wrong on a Rails framework level. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by joining them together, that can mean a lot of things?

Comment: I think "construct the class using 4 models" would be a better way to word it. For example : 

CompetitionSeason.Matches = array of Match model containing the data of Team(Model) and Goals(Model)

Comment: This very much sounds like a job for a database view.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have another model called `Season` or some such which owns (`has_(one|many)`) each of the constituents.

I'm not sure what `Competition` is.

`Match` can belong to either a `Competition` or directly to `Season`. I don't get what `Competition` is so I can't make a good recommendation.

`Goal` should belong to `Match` or `Competition`, and not directly to `Season`. `Season` can still have many goals through `Match` or `Competition`.

`Team` should have a `SeasonTeam` junction table.